# Can APIC LVTERR on AMD be configured as NMI message type?

Tags: amd, interrupt

In fact, the message type / delivery mode of LVTERR on Intel is unconfigured.
[image]

However, on AMD, it is presented as below.
[image]

The problem is, when I configure the MT of LVTERR on AMD as NMI, it will keep causing APIC error. I am not sure about the exactly reason. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confirmed to be configurable. And below explanation is in Linux background.

The project on which I am working requires configuring host LVTERR as NMI. After it had been done, the apic error message kept logging out (you can get it by adding apic=debug to cmd line).

At first, I suspect it is due to the wrong configure to LVTERR on AMD since it has a different depiction to Intel, while most time they are identical.

To check it out, I added some print statements and determined that the error handler for NMI LVTERR is located on do_nmi().

Moreover, I add some print statements with LVTERR's configure reverted. And it turns out the buggy apic error message was always there.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If this post was intended as an answer to the question (as stated in the title - the message body seems to imply a different question), please add more explanation on how you determined that this is the case and what the implications are. If you rather intended it as an update to the question, please edit the question instead.